# Dynamic Dependent Picklist in Pardot

Tags: dependent-picklist, pardot

How can we create dependent picklist in :

- Pardot Forms
- Prospect

With the same feature present as a dependent picklist in Salesforce CRM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create dependent picklists in the Pardot Prospect object, however it is possible to create dependencies in Forms when you add a new field:

[image]

It works a little different than the dependent picklists in Salesforce; Dependent fields are shown depending on values in the 'controlling' field. But it's pretty sophisticated because it only shows dependent fields when necessary. You have to define multiple fields for each dependency to achieve the same result as in Salesforce's dependent picklists.

Comment: is there a workaround to have this kind to functionality/feature implemented in pardot?

Comment: In forms yes, the way I described. In the Pardot objects like Prospect I'm afraid not.

Comment: what is the workaround to have dynamic picklist in Pardot forms as we have in Salesforce.